# preg_replace curly brace when it is the only character on the line?

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
Some Text Here }
}
```

How can I do a preg_replace so that only the "}" on the line by itself gets replaced?

I would expect the following to work, but it doesn't:

```
preg_replace('/^(\s*)(\})(\s*)/', etc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
preg_replace('/^\s*\}\s*$/m', $replacement, $subject);
```

- The `s*` means any number of the character s. What you probably mean is `\s*`, any number of [whitespace characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand).
- You need to enable [multiline](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#multi) mode for the `^` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to work on a per line basis; the default setting is that `^` is the beginning and `$` the end of the entire string, not a single line.
- Remember the `$` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), otherwise something like `}hello` would also get matched.

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `$` matches the beginning and end of a *string*. You need the `m` modifier to make this match the beginning and end of a *line*.

Your RE will not work as expected. `s*` matches zero or more occurences of `s`. It's very likely that you wanted to use `\s*` instead, to match white space.

```
preg_replace('/^(\s*)(\})(\s*)$/m', $replacement, $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

A multi-line free version, that could be used in a larger regex should spanning lines be needed:

`/(^|\n)([^\S\n]*\}[^\S\n]*)(?=\n|$)/`